# How to find repetitive patterns in char array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of characters:

```
a b c x y d e f x y a b c t r e a b c
```

How can I find repetitive  patterns of sizes 2 onwards?

The array needs to be traversed from the end. In the example I need to find patterns `b c`, `a b`, `x y` and patterns of sizes 3: `a b c` and `x y z`. Along with the indices of matching chars.

So far I have tried to traverse the array backwards and find patterns:

```
for (int size = 2; size < aLT.size(); size++) {
    for (int i = aLT.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: pick one language Java or C **?** I think you need only Java.

Comment: Please don't write title with uppercase, this scares me :(

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, you can change the patternSize variable to whatever value you want (well lesser than the size of the input string) :

It takes advantage of the [`String#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method looking for sub sequences of the first String.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int patternSize=4;
    String input = "abcxydefxyabctreabcabcx";
    Set<String> patterns = new TreeSet<String>();

    // test size n patterns
    for (int i=0; i<input.length()-patternSize; i++){
        String pattern = (String) input.subSequence(i, i+patternSize);
        String tester="";
        if (i>0 && i<input.length()-patternSize-1)
            tester = input.substring(0,i)+input.substring(i+patternSize);
        else if (i==0)
            tester = input.substring(i+patternSize);
        else if (i==input.length()-patternSize-1)
            tester = input.substring(0,i);

        if (tester.contains(pattern)){
            patterns.add(pattern);
        }
    }   

    System.out.println("Size "+patternSize+" patterns finder");
    for(String aPattern : patterns){
        System.out.println("The pattern "+aPattern+" was found several times");
    }
}
```

Comment: i need for various sizes 2 onwards(3,4 ...)

Comment: @vijji I edited my code for a generic algorithm for any size n

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 2; // in your case 2 and 3
Map<String, List<Integer>> matches = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
String charsString = new String( chars );
String current = null;
String rest = null;
for( int i = chars.length - n; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    current = charsString.substring( i, i + n );
    rest = charsString.substring( 0, i );
    int index = rest.indexOf( current );
    if( index > -1 ) {
        if( matches.containsKey( current ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        indices.add( i );
        while( index > -1 ) {
            indices.add( index );
            index = rest.indexOf( current, index + 1 );
        }
        matches.put( current, indices );
    }
}

// print the results
for( Entry<String, List<Integer>> match : matches.entrySet() ) {
    System.out.println( match.getKey() + " with indices: " + match.getValue() );
}
```

And the output is:

```
ab with indices: [16, 0, 10]
bc with indices: [17, 1, 11]
xy with indices: [8, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that does what you want to do. All you have to do if you want tofind patterns of different sizes if change patternSize and the strings that are added to the set. At the moment I have it returning a count of the amount of matches but you can easily modify it to return something else such as indices of where the matches begin or a Boolean of whether there are any matches or not.

```
    public static int findPatterns(char[] charArray) {
    int patternSize = 2;
    Set<String> patterns = new HashSet<>();
    patterns.add("bc");
    patterns.add("ab");
    patterns.add("xy");
    int count = 0;
    if (charArray.length < patternSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length - patternSize + 1; i++) {
        String pattern = "";
        for (int j = i; j < i + patternSize; j++) {
            pattern += charArray[j];
        }
        if (patterns.contains(pattern)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```